# Validation in Sitecore Page Editor

Tags: c#, sitecore

I'm using Sitecore 8 and have some trouble with the validation. If the validation occur when I edit the field in Content Editor its work normally, however if I edit it using Experience Editor/Page Editor the one that being validated only the field that is visible in the page such as page heading, title, etc. The field such as metadata is not being validated.. Anyone have any thought about my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a known bug.
I open a ticket to Sitecore Support In Sitecore 8.1 is fixed. 
To fix in 8.0 please follow next steps :

Perform following changes in the App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config file in order to overcome the issue

1. Comment out the following line in the:

   ```
    <pageextender type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.PageExtender.RibbonPageExtender, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon" />
   ```
2. Uncomment the following lines:

   ```
   <pageextender type="Sitecore.Layouts.PageExtenders.PreviewPageExtender, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
   <pageextender type="Sitecore.Layouts.PageExtenders.WebEditPageExtender, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
   <pageextender type="Sitecore.Layouts.PageExtenders.DebuggerPageExtender, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />
   ```

   I wasn't happy with the fixed because it switch to Sheer UI and Sitecore Support  come with other fix.

   To use validation in the Experience Editor with the SPEAK ribbon enabled, please try applying the following workaround:

   1) Put the attached "Sitecore.Support.68029.dll" assembly into your "\bin" folder;

   2) Put the attached "Sitecore.Support.68029.config" file into your "\App_Config\Include" folder.
   Please note that this workaround was not deeply tested, so we recommend you to back up your solution before applying any changes.
   I put on dropbox this two files (dll and config file)

   https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8i9yqvyvvfxn7t/Sitecore.Support.68029.dll?dl=0
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/siv3dff6xfpvuwf/Sitecore.Support.68029.config?dl=0